# Proguard - how do you know what modifications to make to to the proguard file based off the jars and libraries you use?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am having some troubles with Proguard. When I enable Proguard and then try to sign my application package, I get the following errors in my console:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 Warning: com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.MainActivity: can't find referenced field 'int jazzy_pager' in class com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.R$id
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor
 Warning: it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache.DiskLruMultiCache: can't find referenced class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot
       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 Warning: there were 36 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
 Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
          You may need to recompile them and try again.
          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

How do I dictate what modifications I need to make to my Proguard file to sign my application successfully? If anyone could help me out, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend searching this repository https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets in order to find proguard configuration of a library that you use.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on libraries you are using.

Try this:

```
-keepnames class com.jakewharton.disklrucache.** { *; }
-keepnames interface com.jakewharton.disklrucache.** { *; }
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
```